# Counting distinct values of a MongoDB collection property in a limited memory environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The User Schema (Mongoose):

```
{
  "name": String,
  ...
}
```

I need to have a count of **all the distinct** `name`'s without requesting them as a list, like `distinct` method does (collection is too big, can affect the memory).

I have tried to do the following:

```
User
  .distinct('name')
  .count()
  .exec();
```

However `count` method seems to have overwritten the distinct filter returning the count of all objects in the User collection.

What is an efficient way of counting distinct values of a MongoDB collection property in a limited memory environment?

Comment: Can you use the `length()` on the array returned from distinct method ?

Comment: @Veeram the array would be too big, not suited for a limited memory environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using the following aggregation:

```
User.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: null, names:{$addToSet:"$name"} } },
    { $project: { count: { $size: "$names" } } } 
])
.exec(function(err, users){
   console.log(users.count)
})
```

Inside the `$group` aggregation the `$addToSet` operator add each unique name in the `names` array. In `$project` aggregation we count the size of the array `names` by `$size` operator and assign that value to `count` property.